# How to debug the errors of my website on wordpress.org

Tags: wordpress

I am practicing wordpress and have my website on wordpress.org and there is some error because my php file is not working and am trying to find that error and want to see the errors so I have watched the videos to find the errors but I can't able to open the cpanel of my website don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Try WP Debug. See https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Add

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

in wp-config.php and the debug.log file will be in wp-content.

Change the "display" line to true

`define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);`

to dump them to the browser as well as log them.

Answer (score 0):

Open the wp-config.php file and change the following line:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

To:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```